# Exchangeable Random Variables and independence between their indicators

Tags: statistics, random-variables

> $X_1,X_2$ are two exchangeable random variables. Show that the random variable $M = \max\{X_1, X_2\}$ is independent of the indicator random variable $Z = 1_{X_1>X_2}$

I am really struggling to show this: right now my approach is to find the distribution of $P(M>m,Z=1)$ and try to show it equals to $P(M>m)P(Z=1)$. However when I evaluate $P(M>m,Z=1)=P(\max\{X_1, X_2\}>m,X_1>X_2)$, I do not think I can assume the joint density between $M,Z$ which makes it impossible to calculate this probability. How can I proceed with this question?

Comment: Did my answer address your question?

Comment: @ClementC. yes I apologize, I forgot to accept your answer

Comment: No worries! I am a bit curious -- where did this question come from, originally?

Comment: It was a placement exam question (which already ended when I asked the question, I'm just curious about the solution as this is a fun question)

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not true.** Consider $X_1,X_2$ i.i.d. (so *a fortiori* exchangeable) Bernoulli with parameter $1/2$.

Then $\Pr[M=0] = \Pr[X_1=0,X_2=0] = 1/4$, and $\Pr[Z=1] = \Pr[X_1=1,X_2=0] = 1/4$. However,
$$
\Pr[M=0,Z=1] = 0 \neq \Pr[M=0]\cdot \Pr[Z=1]
$$
since $\Pr[M=0,Z=1] = \Pr[X_1=0,X_2=0,X_1>X_2]$